# Codeigniter send form with Ajax and populate and Ajax Data Table

Tags: php, json, ajax, datatable

I'm using codeigniter 3.

I have a view with a form, and I need to submit this form with ajax. No problem with that. The problem is: i have a datatable that's populated with Ajax...when I build datatable, I call an url that return rows to this datatable:

```
"ajax": {
            "url": "<?php echo site_url('clientes/relatorio_atendimentos_buscar')?>",
            "type": "POST"
        },
```

But using a form, how to submit this to a controller, that will return data to datatable?

***EDIT

Changing question to: how to serialize form and call datatable ajax URL on submit?

Answer (score 0):

### The solution

So reading [this](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/21940/how-to-pass-new-post-parameters-on-ajax-reload) post I find this code:

```
"ajax": {
"url": 'filter.php',
"type": 'POST',
"data": function ( d ) {
return $('#formFilter').serialize();
```

And I realize that just need to call that ajax again? Wrong. What should be done is put the whole code that build's datatable inside a function (resultado in this case). When you submit, prevent form submit with this code:

```
$('#relatorio_atendimentos').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    //Call datatable that builds table calling ajax url with serialized array
   resultado();
  });
```